# Markov's inequality intuitions

Tags: density-function, intuition, probability-inequalities

Can someone explain intuitively how Markov's inequality was derived? It seems plausible, but looking a it, I can't 'see' how it's true.

Comment: Could you expand a bit what is bothering you? Otherwise it's too ambiguous to be answerable.

Comment: If you're seeking a proof, the approach of writing an integral and splitting it into two pieces (a similar approach to one that is often used for Chebyshev) should work. Edit: indeed, see here -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Proofs

Comment: To *see* it is true, turn it into $E[X] \ge a\, P(X\ge a)$ and note that for fixed $P(X \ge a)$ and with $P(X \ge 0)=1$, the expectation is going to be minimised when $P(X=a)=P(X \ge a)$ and $P(X=0)=1- P(X \ge a)$ in which case $E[X] = a\, P(X\ge a) +0 \, (1- P(X \ge a))$.  More formally, $E[X]= E[X\mid X\ge a] P(X\ge a) +  E[X\mid 0\le X\lt a] P(X\lt a) \ge a P(X\ge a)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Intuition .  I find it's helpful to plot the function $X$ (as shown at the beginning of that link) and the function $Y$ whose value is $a$ when $X\ge a$ and otherwise whose value is $0,$ so that *obviously* $Y\le X$ when $X$ is a non-negative variable.  Markov's Inequality (trivially!) asserts $E[Y]\le E[X].$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this schematic, the probability space $(\Omega, \Pr)$ is indicated by points on the horizontal axis (arranged, as one can always do, from left to right by increasing values of the non-negative random variable $X$) with lengths representing probabilities; and real values are indicated on the vertical axis.  It depicts the random variable $X$ with the black graph along with the related random variable $Z = a\mathcal{I}(X\le a)$ in red.  $Z$ is constructed to ensure $Z(\omega)\le X(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega.$

Expectations (values times probabilities) are represented by areas in the plot: the gray area beneath the graph of $X$ (including the red area) is its expectation and the red area beneath the red graph is the expectation of $Z.$

[image]

***Markov's Inequality* notes that the expectation of $Z$ is the area of the red rectangle,** equal to its height $a$ times its base $\Pr(X\ge a),$ and therefore

> $$a\Pr(X\ge a) = E[Z] \le E[X].$$

Clearly this is the best universal lower bound of this sort, because when $X=Z$ (that is, $X$ is a binary random variable), the inequality is an equality.  But we can generalize it in various ways by choosing more complicated comparison variables $Z$ (*e.g.,* consider comparing $X$ to an ascending sequence of values $a_1\lt a_2 \lt a_3 \lt \cdots,$ which will produce a linear combination of values of the distribution function $F_X$ on the left hand side) or by varying $a$ to maximize the area of the red rectangle.

---

**NB:** Any measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure can be represented accurately this way.  For other measures you have to read the plot a little more abstractly, but the analysis is no different.