# How to obtain moment bound from importance sampling identity?

Tags: probability, random-variable, probability-inequalities, importance-sampling

Let $m(t) =E[X^t].$ The moment bound states that for **a > 0,** $$P\{ X \geq a \}\leq m(t)a^{-t} \forall t > 0 .$$   How would you prove this  result using importance sampling identity?

**My answer:**
The importance sampling identity states that for any measurable function $f$ and random variable $X$ with probability density function $p$, the expected value of $f(X)$ can be expressed as:

$$E[f(X)] = \int f(x) p(x) dx = \int f(x) \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} q(x) dx,$$

where $q$ is another probability density function that we choose. This identity allows us to estimate $E[f(X)]$ by sampling from $q$ instead of $p$.

Now, let's move on to proving the moment bound using the importance sampling identity. We want to show that for any positive number $a$ and any positive exponent $t$, the probability that $X^t$ is greater than or equal to $a^t$ is bounded by $m(t) \cdot a^{-t}$.

To do this, we will choose the function $f(x) = \mathbb{I}(x \geq a)$, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function that takes the value $1$ if the condition inside the parentheses is true, and $0$ otherwise. By applying the importance sampling identity to $f(x^t)$, we have:

$$E[f(X^t)] = \int \mathbb{I}(x^t \geq a^t) \frac{p(x^t)}{q(x^t)} q(x^t) dx^t.$$

Now, notice that when $x^t \geq a^t$, the indicator function takes the value $1$, and $0$ otherwise. Therefore, we can rewrite the above expression as:

$$E[f(X^t)] = \int \mathbb{I}(x^t \geq a^t) \frac{p(x^t)}{q(x^t)} q(x^t) dx^t = \int_{x^t \geq a^t} \frac{p(x^t)}{q(x^t)} q(x^t) dx^t.$$

Now, let's focus on the integral $\int_{x^t \geq a^t} \frac{p(x^t)}{q(x^t)} q(x^t) dx^t$. We can rewrite this integral as the expectation of the random variable $\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t)$, where $X^t$ is sampled from the distribution $q$. Therefore, we have:

$$E[f(X^t)]=\int_{x^t \geq a^t} \frac{p(x^t)}{q(x^t)} q(x^t) dx^t = E\left[\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t)\right].$$

Now, since $\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t)$ is a non-negative random variable, we can apply Markov's inequality, which states that for any non-negative random variable $Y$ and any positive constant $c$, we have $P\{Y \geq c\} \leq \frac{E[Y]}{c}$. Applying Markov's inequality to our expression, we get:

$$P\left\{\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t) \geq {a^t}\right\} \leq \frac{E\left[\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t)\right]}{a^t} =m(t) {a^{-t}}.$$

But notice that the event $\left\{\frac{p(X^t)}{q(X^t)} \cdot q(X^t) \geq {a^t}\right\}$ is equivalent to the event $\left\{X \geq a\right\}$. Therefore, we have:

$$P\left\{X \geq a\right\} \leq {m(t)}{a^{-t}}.$$

And there you have it! We have successfully proved the moment bound using the importance sampling identity. This result tells us that for any positive number $a$ and any positive exponent $t$, the probability that $X^t$ is greater than or equal to $a^t$ is bounded by $m(t) \cdot a^{-t}$.

I think now this answer seems to look correct. Isn't it?

Comment: Given that the standard demonstration is [dead simple](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625511), the purpose of this exercise seems obscure.  Are you perhaps hoping to derive some insight into importance sampling in this fashion?

Comment: Re your edit: this is extraordinarily circular, because you are asking how to prove Markov's Inequality for the non-negative random variable $X^t$ and you invoke that very inequality in the demonstration!

Comment: @whuber, By looking at your comment, it seems that  my edited answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: As a proof, it is illogical.